# How can I adjust the z-index of a form in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I maintain a fairly large ms-access 2003 application.  One of the recent changes that I was asked to make was to add a popup dialog box to warn used of a particular situation when the opened a form which is itself a pop up (although not modal) form.

Unfortunately, the new popup modal form comes up behind the original one, getting the user interface into an impossible position (you cannot close the modal dialog box because it is hidden, but you cannot move the others out the way because the modal dialog is preventing you).

I've temporarily made the new box come up to the very side of the screen but it is far from ideal.

Is there a way to specify the Z index of a form so I can control the layering? (or any other solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to control this is by the order in which you open the forms.

I.e. you have to **first** open the original popup form, **then** open the new modal popup.

You could also consider using `MsgBox()` instead of the new form.

Comment: Yes, strictly true, VERY strictly/! I was opening dialog from within the Current event and it was not displaying on top.  I added a slight delay (using the timer) and now it always appears on top

Comment: I should add something else for the unwary.  If the form has no records, then the Current event doesn't occur. I ended up doing it, with a longer timer, in the Open event.